# jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_Confirm_KEY). Property 'id' does not exist on type 'object'

Tags: node.js, typescript

this is my code

```
const data = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_Confirm_KEY);
```

when i use data.id i get error

```
await db.ref(`/users/${data.id}`).once("value")
```

> Property 'id' does not exist on type 'object'.ts(2339)

one way to get rid of the error

```
interface IdEmail {
  id: string;
  email: string;
}

const data = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_Confirm_KEY) as IdEmail;
```

what other ways are there to get rid of this error ?

Comment: What JWT package do you use?

Comment: `import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";`

Comment: Any way you go, you're going to have to define the properties of `data` (unless you just declare it as `any`).

Comment: So there are only two options.1)`const data = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_Confirm_KEY) as IdEmail;`,  2)`const data: any = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_Confirm_KEY);`.

Comment: I believe so, yes.

Answer (score 1):

After you verify, you must decode token. Try this:

```
const { id, email } = jwt.decode(token, { json: true }) as IdEmail;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom generic function, it will look the same as your comment, but I think this way will be better.

```
const verify = <T extends object>(token: string, secret: string): T => {
  return jwt.verify(token, secret) as T;
};

const sign = <T extends object>(payload: T, secret: string): string => {
  return jwt.sign(payload, secret);
};

export default const MyJwt = {
  sign,
  verify,
}
```

Usage,

```
import MyJwt from './MyJwt';

const data = MyJwt.verify<IdEmail>(token, process.env.JWT_Confirm_KEY);
// data now is a IdEmail
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be another minimal approach with Typescript. Note that you also could use the decoded data already within the `jwt.verify` callback. I just prefer to do it this way for program control flow.

```
let isJWTValid = false;

jwt.verify(token, "mysecret", (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
        return;
    }

    isJWTValid = true;
});

if (!isJWTValid) {
    return "invalid token";
}

const decodedToken = jwt.decode(token) as { myValue: string }; // <--- Cast here for Typescript

const { myValue } = decodedToken;

console.log("myValue", myValue);
```